# How to find files in directory that has element matching xpath

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

To look for element by xpath i do:

```
Select-Xml -XPath "//node[a='1']" -Xml $xml
```

Is there a simple way (without loop) to look for all files under this directory that has element with this xpath?

Something similar to text search:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Include *.* | Select-String "text to search for"
```

version - Powershell3

Comment: Are *all* the files XML files and you want to look for the XPath pattern inside the XML file?  If so then do `Get-ChildItem . -r -file | Select-Xml -XPath "//node[a='1']"`.

Comment: Forgive me for the stupid question. Select-Xml should get single xml as input. How come that you send a list of files as an input ?

Comment: Select-Xml can be provided a list of XML files that it will load as XML and process.  If you look at the help on Select-Xml you will see that the `LiteralPath` parameter accepts pipeline input as well as direct input i.e. an array of paths.

Comment: I looked in the help . The LiteralPath  is one of the input parameters. Why when you use pipe in this way powershell know to translate it to LiteralPath  as input?

Comment: Read this - http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/effective-powershell-item-11-understanding-bypropertyname-pipeline-bound-parameters/  Apologies for the code formatting.  The site was automatically ported over to WordPress and a lot of the code formatting got borked.  You can also grab the ebook from this post and read the same chapter: http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/effective-windows-powershell-the-free-ebook/  BTW, is this what you are after i.e. does it answer your question?

Comment: Can you wrote this as an answer in order to close the question? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe the files you want to do an XPath search directly into `Select-Xml` like so:

```
Get-ChildItem . -r -file | Select-Xml -XPath "//node[a='1']"
```

For more information on how the output of Get-ChildItem gets "connected" to the LiteralPath parameter of Select-Xml, see this [blog post](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2008/04/06/effective-powershell-item-11-understanding-bypropertyname-pipeline-bound-parameters/).  You can get the whole [Effective PowerShell free ebook from here](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/03/08/effective-windows-powershell-the-free-ebook/).

Comment: You should add reference to your post. Its great post.